# Debugging an installed .NET application

Tags: .net, debugging, exception, visual-studio-debugging

Dealing with an error which only seems to occur with an installed .NET 4.0 application on only about half of the machines the application has been installed on.

Is there any way to debug the installed files?

So if the files are in `C:\Program files\MyProgram\` containing `MyProgram.exe` and all required dlls, can I somehow debug `MyProgram.exe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the source code and the pdb files are on the machine you want to debug from you should be able to do a remote debugger session. [Here is the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t.aspx) on how to set it up.